# NestJS TypeORM mysql Connection error (DataSource initialization error) - using VSCode/Docker

Tags: mysql, initialization, datasource, typeorm

I'm building a server app with NestJS, using TypeORM and a MySQL database. Recently I tried to migrate to the recommended TypeORM configuration/connection mode: using a DataSource. Before this, using an ormconfig.js file I had no issues.
I'm running Windows 11, Docker with 2 images (mysql, adminer) and VSCode to run my server. I (pull and) create and run docker images & container via `docker-compose up` and the following yaml file:

```
version: "4.25.2"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

In the server app I load my database config parameters via the environment (.env). The file is defined as:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=gymmy_db
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=test
DB_TYPE=mysql
NODE_ENV=development
```

I have a separate file in my 'src' directory (data-source.ts), with the DataSource object:

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    migrations: ['migrations/*.js'],
    type: "mysql",
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,   
    entities: ['**/*.entity.js'],  
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" 
    ? true 
    : false,
    logging: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" 
    ? true 
    : false,
    migrationsRun: process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" 
    ? true 
    : false,
});
```

Since I was not sure if the environment variables were loaded before the DataSource object was created, I re-set the DataSourceOptions in my main.ts file, after the AppModule is created (and thus the ConfigModule as well). I check the correct loading of the environment variables and the setting of the DataSourceOptions via two console logging lines:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppDataSource } from 'src/data-source';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  
  console.log(`LOG 1: Host: ${process.env.DB_HOST}, Port: ${process.env.DB_PORT}, PW: ${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}, User: ${process.env.DB_USER}, NAME: ${process.env.DB_NAME}`);
  
  AppDataSource.setOptions({
    migrations: ['migrations/*.js'],
    type: "mysql",
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,   
    entities: ['**/*.entity.js'],  
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" 
    ? true 
    : false,
    logging: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" 
    ? false 
    : false,
    migrationsRun: process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" 
    ? true 
    : false,
  });
  
  console.log(`LOG 2: Type: ${AppDataSource.options.type}, Sync: ${AppDataSource.options.synchronize}, DB: ${AppDataSource.options.database}, Entities: ${AppDataSource.options.entities}`);
  await AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
      console.log("Data Source has been initialized!")
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err)
  });
  
  // Set input validation globally -> Not possible anymore to change it locally for specific routes
  // Consider introducing it locally for every route and using groups
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    // Enforces whitelisting in request bodies (controllers): 
    // key-values that are not specified in the dto (that do not have a validation decorator) are filtered out.
    whitelist: true,
  }
  ));  
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Then when I run the server app, I get the following error, where it seems as if my DataSource parameters were not used (`"Access denied for user ''@'172.20.0.1' (using password: NO)"`):

```
[16:52:51] Starting compilation in watch mode...
[16:52:54] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +14ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] ContactsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] PersonsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] EmailsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
LOG 1: Host: localhost, Port: 3307, PW: test, User: root, NAME: gymmy_db
LOG 2: Type: mysql, Sync: true, DB: gymmy_db, Entities: **/*.entity.js
Error during Data Source initialization Error: Access denied for user ''@'172.20.0.1' (using password: NO)
    at Packet.asError (C:\wamp64\www\gymmy_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\wamp64\www\gymmy_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\wamp64\www\gymmy_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:478:34)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\wamp64\www\gymmy_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\wamp64\www\gymmy_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\gymmy_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:376:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:349:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:286:10) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'172.20.0.1' (using password: NO)",
  sql: undefined
}
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +268ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RoutesResolver] UsersController {/users}: +1ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RoutesResolver] ContactsController {/contacts}: +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RoutesResolver] PersonsController {/persons}: +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RoutesResolver] EmailsController {/emails}: +1ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +0ms
[Nest] 844  - 23-11-2023 16:52:55     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +4ms
```

When I completely removed my docker container and images, and did a new pull+create using the same yaml file but with one change: the port set to 3307 (I checked when it was running), I also changed my environment variable DB_PORT to 3307, and then ran the app again:

```
[17:07:37] Starting compilation in watch mode...
[17:07:40] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +13ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] ContactsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] PersonsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] EmailsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
LOG 1: Host: localhost, Port: 3307, PW: test, User: root, NAME: gymmy_db
LOG 2: Type: mysql, Sync: true, DB: gymmy_db, Entities: **/*.entity.js
Error during Data Source initialization AggregateError: 
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  fatal: true,
  [errors]: [
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 3306
    },
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3306
    }
  ]
}
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +235ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RoutesResolver] UsersController {/users}: +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RoutesResolver] ContactsController {/contacts}: +1ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RoutesResolver] PersonsController {/persons}: +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RoutesResolver] EmailsController {/emails}: +0ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +1ms
[Nest] 9348  - 23-11-2023 17:07:41     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

Also a connection error, but it appears it is trying to connect via port 3306, and not using my environment variable. Nevertheless my logging shows that the environment variable is available and the `setOptions` has worked.
Can anybody point me in the right direction for a solution?
I have searched a lot online, but I could not find a similar problem (let alone solution). I did experiment a lot with the position of the `setOptions` and `initialize`, with re-installations of docker & images (but since my old version is still working, I expect docker is not my problem).
I see no (big) differences with the recommended code from the typeORM help site. So I'm out of possible solutions.

Update
Thanks user1191247 for pointing out this bug. The workaround is not possible, since the `driver.options` only extends the BaseDataSourceOptions, and not the MysqlConnectionCredentialsOptions, as does the MysqlConnectionOptions used in the `setOptions` or constructor. This makes it impossible to apply host/port/username/password. I might have to switch back indeed to the nestJS implementation; the bug report implied that the DataSource constructor should work, but creating the AppDataSource object after initialization of the Config Module, gives a lot of headaches for other Repository objects that are derived from AppDataSource using `getRepository`, since the AppDataSource is still undefined during initialization.

Comment: [This bug](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9060) relates to the options passed to setOptions not being passed through to the driver. One of the suggested workarounds is to `AppDataSource.driver.options = AppDataSource.options;`. It may be cleaner and easier to use Nest's [TypeORM Integration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration).